# Adding SSH-key through curl: Fingerprint cannot be generated

Tags: git, bash, curl, gitlab, ssh-keys

I'm writing an bash script that will add an `SSH-key` to an in-house Gitlab server. Below is the code:

```
userToken=$(curl http://gitserver/api/v3/session --data 'login=*****&password=****' | jq '.private_token')
userToken=$(echo "$userToken" | tr -d '"')

# Below key is for testing, will use output of cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub later on
sshKey="ssh-rsa AA*********L ****@***com"

curl --data "private_token=$userToken&title=keyName&key=$sshKey" "http://gitserver/api/v3/user/keys"
```

But I get this response:

```
{
  "message": {
    "fingerprint": [
      "cannot be generated"
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I mannualy insert the same key through the webbrowser, everything is just working fine...

So what am I doing wrong? Do I miss an option?

Comment: Short question: Can curl/GitLab handle spaces in post strings, or do you need to url-encode your POST data? You could try using `curl --data-urlencode` instead of `curl --data`.

Comment: @ErikE.Lorenz Looks like this could be the problem and fix! Only problem... I'm taken from the project. But I passed this information to the person in charge (although he has no time to try). But since this looks like it could fix the problem you can create an official answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: https://jxqc.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/gitlab-key-is-invalid-fingerprint-cannot-be-generated/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the spaces in your SSH pubkey weren't properly escaped. Some characters cannot be used in the POST DATA string, including spaces.

Try using `curl --data-urlencode` instead of `curl --data` to automatically encode the POST data.

Answer (score 2):

*OP here*

In the mean time I've updated the server to version 8.8 and changed the `curl` code a bit and now it's working like a charm:

```
curl -X POST -F "private_token=${userToken}" -F "title=${sshName}" -F "key=${sshKey}" "${gitServer}/user/keys"
```

*Just in case anybody needs this in the future...*